# Transcations, API's and Designing for Failure

Tags: django, api, transactions, acid

I have been working on an application that needs to log credit card transactions which is dependent on using an external API. Within my application, I have the concept of an invoice with a total, and a transaction that when successful credit card payment is made, deducts from this total.

This is more of a platform independent question, but I am working with Django, Python and MySQL.

My question centers mainly around the use of transactions when dealing with external API's and how to design your software to handle potential failures. Both Django and MySQL support transactions, so that in itself is not an issue, but suppose the following scenario:

- Credit card submitted though the payment API
- Credit card is successfully processed
- This response is then logged to the database as a payment on that invoice
- There is an error saving the payment to the database for one reason or another

What do you do now?

If there was not an API call involved the answer would be clear, rollback the database transaction and raise an error. But having a call to an external API complicates matters, because this is not really a way to rollback on the external API call.

I am interested if anyone has run into this issue (for credit cards, or similar types of transactions) and how they addressed the problem, or in general some approaches for software design in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to manage this in software. However, if your payment gateway is calling a callback to signify that the transaction is successful, it will presumably log an error if that callback fails to complete, and you should be able to configure it to alert you in that case, perhaps by email. Then it's up to you to rectify the situation manually.

Comment: In my case, the api call is made directly in the software controller where I get a response from the credit card transaction. Even with logging in place, ideally there would not have to be a manual step. To be ACID compliant, the full transaction would need to be able to be rolled back.